# GitHub: How can I mark a task in a issue with commit message?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I know how to close an issue with a confirmation message, but I would like to know if it is possible to verify a task in an issue.

I don't close a issue, just a task #3

´´´
(Open) 2 of 5 tasks
**Issue name #1**

- [x] task#1
- [x] task#2
- [] task#3
- [] task#4
- [] task#5

´´´

git commit -m ":tada: (init) First files fix task #1#3 "